# Find (unix) - routing standard output from multiple -exec primaries to multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If this is answered somewhere then I've spent a long time searching but just haven't found the right terms to use to find out if or how it's done. So…

Is it possible using one Unix `find` command that executes several other commands using multiple `-exec` primaries to write the standard output of each of the embedded commands to a different output file? I know I could pipe results on to further commands to handle the various needs but really want to know if multiple redirections can be used in the following way. (BTW, I'm not worried about security issues…this is just for an ad hoc request on my own machine

I want to use `find` to locate all broken symbolic links in my home directory tree like this:

```
find -L ~ -type l -print
```

but I'd like to take the results and execute two different `ls` commands for each broken link found (`ls {}` to get just the paths and `ls -l {}` to get a list of the paths and the file they should be linking to ):

```
find -L ~ -type l -exec ls {} \; -exec ls -l {} \;
```

That works well (I've tested it with some `echo` commands surrounding the various embedded `ls` commands to be sure) but when I attempt to redirect the standard output of each `ls` command to a different file like this:

```
find -L ~ -type l -exec ls {} >>ls1 \; -exec ls -l {} >>ls2 \;
```

the output from both `ls` commands ends up in the last file specified (`ls2`). I'm guessing that the redirections are being taken as part of the `find` command and that the last redirection must override those before it. I've tried putting quotes around the redirections to make them part of the `ls` commands but then they are taken as file names by `ls` and I've tried using back slashes (`\`) before the `>`'s with similar results. I'm not sure if it can be done or not but I can't find the right syntax if it can. Can someone enlighten me about what might be done. (I'm really not looking for 'best ways' to do this specific task since I can think of plenty of other ways that it could be done but would really like to know specifically if multiple redirections can be done within one find command in some way.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work. bash handles the redirections **before** it calls `find`, thus `find` won't see them. And if find would see them, it could not handle them because find has no option to do any redirections.

Thus the best you can do to keep your code short is:

```
find -L ~ -type l -exec bash -c 'ls "{}" >>ls1' \; -exec bash -c 'ls -l "{}" >>ls2' \;
```

Also, note the double quotes around the `{}` added to handle filenames containing blanks.

Comment: I think that's probably as good a way as I wanted. Note I edited your answer to put the double quotes around the curly brackets for names with blanks after testing it and seeing the problem.